# how to delete or add column in grid panel

Tags: extjs, extjs3

grid.getcolumnModel().setHidden(0,true) will be effected for column menu
 and not grid panel. In column menu u can enable or disable the column. How do we add or remove the column in grid panel dynamically?

Answer (score 6):

I think this is what you are looking for http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?53009-Adding-removing-fields-and-columns

Make sure you look at post #37 in the thread as well.

Comment: The idea is to have here the solution to the question and then a reference to look for more details... just a link... sight.

Answer (score 2):

For those who reach this question looking for a solution for Ext.js 4.2 and avobe.

I use "reconfigure" method to dynamically change the grid columns: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-reconfigure

Here is a nice example: http://marcusschiesser.de/2013/12/21/dynamically-changing-the-structure-of-a-grid-in-extjs-4-2/

Answer (score 0):

You may have to refresh the Ext.grid.GridView in order for the column change to show.

```
grid.getView().refresh(true) // true to refresh HeadersToo
```

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJs 3.x this piece of code can help:

*Note: I have used checkbox, as the first column. Please remove that line if you don't need it.*

```
var newColModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
    columns: [
        grid.getSelectionModel(),
        {
            header: 'New column 1'
        }, {
            header: 'New column 2'
        }
    ],
    defaults: {
        sortable: false
    }
});

grid.store.reader = new Ext.data.JsonReader({
    root: 'items',
    totalProperty: 'count',
    fields: [
        // Please provide new array of fields here
    ]
});

grid.reconfigure(grid.store, newColModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `reconfigure` function might not work well with plugins. Especially if you have something like `FilterBar`.

If you only need to do this once, based on some global settings that use can use `initComponent` and change your initial config. Be sure to make all changes to the config *before* calling `this.callParent();`

Tested with ExtJS 6.2 (but should also work for ExtJS 4 and 5)

```
initComponent: function() {
    // less columns for this setting
    if (!app.Settings.dontUseFruits()) {
        var newColumns = [];
        for(var i=0; i<this.columns.items.length; i++) {
            var column = this.columns.items[i];
            // remove (don't add) columns for which `dataIndex` starts with "fruit"
            if (column.dataIndex.search(/^fruit/) < 0) {
                newColumns.push(column);
            }
        }
        this.columns.items = newColumns;
    }

    this.callParent();
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try

store.add(new_record);
store.commitChanges();

or store.remove() and store.commitChanges()